# Adding custom fields on checkout and save to database on magento 2.1

Tags: magento2, checkout, onepage-checkout, custom

I have added custom fields on checkout page. The fields are displayed properly. But I want to save the custom fields to database too. 
I found some guide to do that but no luck. 
Can anybody have insight on it? Please help.

Comment: Can you share more detail about that?

Comment: I'm dying trying to do that... did you solved? can you please update the question with source code? So they will be more likely to help us. I'm on the same point, I'm viewing the fields but they are not saving on the ddbb

Answer (score -2):

I am not sure whether you've checked out this sample module: add extensible attributes.
https://github.com/magento/magento2-samples/blob/master/sample-external-links/README.md

Comment: Your link explains to how add an external link with an additional attribute for a product. In checkout and regarding the question above, it's far to be the right answer, not even a clue to start to find a solution,